# What is Juggernaut's armor made of, and how did he get it?

Tags: marvel, x-men

**I was wondering what the armor of Juggernaut is made of.** From some comics I read (no idea which universe), and from the movies, it appears to be some kind of thick, heavy metal. But I would be surprised that it is of a regular alloy, like steel, as that would wear far too rapidly.

**I'm also unknown to its origins.** Did he always have that cumbersome metal 'dome' over his head/shoulders ?  Is it possibly magical ?

*Disclaimer: I'm mostly familiar with the movies' canon (as far as you can call it that re. the movies), and to a very limited extent, the comics.  Doesn't matter in what universe the answer comes from.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Juggernaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_Marko), or Cain Marko, has his durability come from the Crimson Gem of Cyttorak. This gives him a mystical invisible force field that protects his entire body from all damage once he is in motion.  This force field extends to the protection of his clothing.  The original armor (red) was the uniform of the avatar of Cyttorak. However even his civilain clothing is protected from damage once he is in motion. His major weakness once he gains any momentum is mental attack.  The "dome" helmet protects him from this.  He also wears a metal skull cap underneath the helmet made of the same metal as Magneto's helmet that blocks psi-energy.  His film counterpart portrayed by Vinnie Jones is a mutant with no mystical abilities.  His helmet was constructed in the realm of Cyttorak by a metal found there, as was his skullcap at a later time. The helmet protects him from psionic attacks, especially from his stepbrother Charles Xavier. He made the skullcap so that, if the helmet was taken, he’d still be protected.

Comment: As far as I know, Juggernaut's powers are not restricted to when he is in motion. Wikipedia cites that he is "physically unstoppable once in motion", but that just means that his movement can't be physically stopped against his will, not that his invulnerability is restricted to his momentum.

Comment: Actually he can be harmed if not in motion, but he has a mystic healing ability that prevents any permanent damage.  Shatterstar's sword has cut him before as well as other mystical beings.

Comment: The gem is the reason why he is not permenantly damaged.

Comment: @Johnnybravo - I'm fairly sure that's only in the comics, not the film canon.